# Rails: How to direct to results page on form 'submit'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, formbuilder

I would like to direct users to a 'results' page when they click the submit button of an 8 question multi-choice quiz, while also saving their answers to the database.

At the moment I'm using 'form_for' and passing in current_user. When submit is clicked it is therefore directed to the User/show action. I would like to go to a page that details a user's results. How would I go about doing that?

Here's my (very rough test) form with, so far, one multi-choice question (styled by bootstrap):

```
<%= form_for([current_user]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field(:user, :name) %>
  </p>
  <div class="btn-group-vertical clearfix form-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-primary text-left">
            <input name="options" id="option1" type="radio" onclick="multiChoiceClick(1, 1)">A. Always. I'm the leader and should have the final say
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-primary text-left">
            <input name="options" id="option2" type="radio">B. Sometimes, but I think the group should make decisions if possible
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-primary text-left">
            <input name="options" id="option3" type="radio">C. I generally don't get involved. The group can make their own decisions without my help
          </label>
  </div>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit("Get my results!") %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I'm currently including the text_field with the user's name just as a test.

I'd like to know how to 'wire up' the first multi-choice question to a User, but display a results page when 'get my results' is clicked.

I may well have several things wrong in this code. If I do, and you have an answer, could you please point out what I've got wrong AND explain the correct way to do that thing? Sorry to be so specific, but I've had a few comments previously that ONLY point out what's wrong, with no alternative.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Someone asked for the controller, so here it is:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def whattypeofleader
        @user = current_user
        #@quiz_answer = current_user.quiz_answers(0).build
    end

    def post_params
        params.require(:quiz_answer).permit(:body, :user_id)
    end
end
```

I have the @quiz_answer commented out because I wasn't sure how to link it up with the form. In the User controller, User has_many :quiz_answers and QuizAnswer belongs_to :user

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The redirection should come from your controller.
After you managed your datas, a simple :

`redirect_to results_path`

Your results path should be in your `config/routes.rb`.

Don't hesitate to share a little bit more, like your controller, to see if we can go deeper :)

**[EDIT] following the comments**

*disclaimer : not sure about the plural management of quizzes by Rails...*

Your form should be rendered by the `new` method, like so :

```
class QuizzesController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def new
    @user = current_user     #you now have access to the @user variable in your view
  end

  ...
  def create
    # do your thing with your params
    # usually, you want to redirect to the results page if the action has been saved
    # so let's say that you built an @object beforehand with the params you received
    # extactly like @DarkMousse answer :

    if @object.save
      redirect_to results_path
      flash[:notice] = "Thanks for submitting these questions"
    else
      render 'new'
    end

    # this way, if all is good, go to results_path, else, return to the 'new'

  end
  ...

end
```

In order to access this action, you have to have a route to get to it, let's go to `config/routes.rb`

```
YouApplicationName::Application.routes.draw do
  ...
  #it 'opens' the routes to access all method from your quizzes controller
  resources :quizzes
  resources :results
  ...
end
```

Now you can access quizzes/new. It will render the view in `views/quizzes/new`, in which you could have a form like so :

```
form_for @user do |f|
  # ... your form ...
end
```

Note that @user is accessible thanks to our `new` method in our QuizzesController.

Now that we added a `results` to our routes, with a `rake routes` in the terminal you should find a `results_path` leading to your (yet to create :) ) `ResultsController` `index` method.

It could be looking like this :

```
class ResultsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # in order to access all the results in our view
    @results = Results.all
  end
end
```

This way, the `results_path` is leading to this action, which by default (thanks to rails) is calling `views/results/index.html.erb` to render.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've added the HomeController above and some details about the User and QuizAnswer relationship. I think my big problem is I don't see where these *_path helpers come from. Where, or how, would I generate a results_path?

Comment: Your `home_controller` should not manage your user. If it's for managing your quizzes, go ahead and create a QuizzController. In the `new` method, you can get your user and pass it to your view ( `@user = current_user`).
You would have in your `views/quizzes/new.html.erb` a `form_for @user`.

Rails form helper will take care of sending the submission datas to your `create`method in your `QuizzController`, and it's there that you will be managing your params. 

Am I clear ? You can say no !

Comment: Gah! I think there's a lot to appreciate at once. When you say 'in the new method' is that the 'new' method of the QuizAnswer controller? And - currently the form is a partial, rendered as part of the home/whattypeofleaderareyou.html.erb view. But you're saying the form should be in quizzes/new.html.erb, right? I'll give that a go and see what happens...

Comment: I've edited my answer for the `new` method and routes.

Comment: OK It's working with the new QuizzesController. It still updates and shows the user's profile when I hit submit. How would I send it to a results page? (Thanks again for your answer - this feels like the first real progress I've made in a week!). Also I changed the 'whattypeofleader' path to get "whattypeofleader" => "quizzes#new" in routes.rb; Including resources :quizzes or not didn't make any difference. Is that a problem?

Comment: I've updated my answer to follow the path to the results

Comment: OK, I'll have to digest all of that, but it's looking VERY promising! Thank you so much for taking the time to do that. I DO have a question: What about the 'new' action in the QuizzesController renders the form? In future, I'd like to be able to tell what my code is doing and I have no clue WHY (or how) that function (consisting of just one line) renders the form. Is there another association made beforehand somewhere that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Rails is based on the "convention over configuration". The idea is that if you follow the framework conventions, you won't have to configure "basic" things like so. Here, the QuizzesController will look in your folder `views/quizzes/*` by default, because you didn't specify anything. It's rails magic. Can be surprising at first, but trust me, over time, it really is awesome. You have the right reflex though, trying to understanding it. More info about the rendering : http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: If you're new at Rails, a great first step could be https://www.railstutorial.org/ , which you could read online for free on the website. It takes you from the start to a really understanding place :) Git, TDD and so on along the way. 
Good luck !

Comment: Yeah, I've been reading the Hartl book and the guides, but it's just too easy to lose the thread of what they're talking about. I think I've made some assumptions that aren't right; Up until yesterday I thought resources correlated to Models, but it looks like that might not be the case. But I'll go through your example again today and see how far I get. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66559/discussion-between-moosefetcher-and-stanboyet).

Answer (score 0):

Submitting a form involves a `POST` request. Therefore, you are sending data to the server. In Rails, this can be accomplished through the `Create Action`. Do something like this in your `Home Controller`

```
def create
  @question = Question.new
  if @question.save
    redirect_to results_path
    flash[:notice] = "Thanks for submitting these questions"
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add  "redirect_to results_path" in the corresponding controller at once the object is successfully saved into the database.